# JSON Length giving the incorrect value

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, xml2js

I want to get the length of the JSON, but it's not giving the values i want. I am using XML to JSON converter library (xml2js). If do you know another library than xml2js. I can use it too.

> console.log(result.length) -> Returns the **2**, which is correct.

```json
   {
  LISTENER: [
    {
      CONNECTTIME: { _text: '4880' },
      UID: { _text: '57' },
      XFF: {},
      GRID: { _text: '57' },
      TRIGGERS: { _text: '0' }
    },
    {
      CONNECTTIME: { _text: '254' },
      UID: { _text: '65' },
      XFF: {},
      GRID: { _text: '65' },
      TRIGGERS: { _text: '0' }
    }
  ]
}
```

But if i delete one record from the JSON like the below.

> console.log(result.length) -> Returns the 9, which is wrong. I want it to be 1. Where am i doing wrong?

```json
{
    LISTENER: {
        CONNECTTIME: { _text: '4587' },
        UID: { _text: '57' },
        XFF: {},
        GRID: { _text: '57' },
        TRIGGERS: { _text: '0' }
    }
}
```

Can someone help me? Is there a any force options to make both records convert to array.

---

**Additional Information For Help;**

---

Here is the code.

```js
var options = {ignoreComment: true, alwaysChildren: true, compact: true}
var result = convert.xml2js(response.data, options);
            
console.log("listeners.listener:"+Object.keys(result.SHOUTCASTSERVER.LISTENERS.LISTENER).length);
console.log(util.inspect(result.SHOUTCASTSERVER.LISTENERS, false, null, true /* enable colors */))
```

response.data is the respond of the get request(using axios library) from website. Gives the body of the XML page.

```
This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.
<SHOUTCASTSERVER>
<LISTENERS>
<LISTENER>
<CONNECTTIME>350</CONNECTTIME>
<UID>66</UID>
<XFF/>
<GRID>66</GRID>
<TRIGGERS>0</TRIGGERS>
</LISTENER>
</LISTENERS>
</SHOUTCASTSERVER>
```

XML page converting with library (XMLtoJS)
Output of the result (If there is 1 record converting like this);

```
{
  _declaration: {
    _attributes: { version: '1.0', encoding: 'UTF-8', standalone: 'yes' }
  },
  SHOUTCASTSERVER: {
    LISTENERS: {
      LISTENER: {
        CONNECTTIME: { _text: '657' },
        UID: { _text: '66' },
        XFF: {},
        GRID: { _text: '66' },
        TRIGGERS: { _text: '0' }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Output of the result (2 Record Output);

```
{
  _declaration: {
    _attributes: { version: '1.0', encoding: 'UTF-8', standalone: 'yes' }
  },
  SHOUTCASTSERVER: {
    LISTENERS: {
      LISTENER: [
        {
          CONNECTTIME: { _text: '819' },
          UID: { _text: '66' },
          XFF: {},
          GRID: { _text: '66' },
          TRIGGERS: { _text: '0' }
        },
        {
          CONNECTTIME: { _text: '3' },
          UID: { _text: '68' },
          XFF: {},
          GRID: { _text: '68' },
          TRIGGERS: { _text: '0' }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: The two Objects are different, unclear

Comment: What do you mean length of JSON? Can you also add what you expect the correct values to be for each scenario? Are you attempting to find the length of the array of the length of the JSON string?

Comment: How is different? Can you explain please

Comment: Um, one is an array, one is an object. `LISTENER: []` is not `LISTENER: {}`

Comment: I am using xml2js(xml to json) library. I think its converts to that way if there is multiple values.

Comment: Well there would be your problem. Guess you need to detect if you have an Object or an Array and act accordingly

Comment: So how can i force to xml2js library to make  them both object? I couldn't find them in the options for converting.  https://www.npmjs.com/package/xml2js

Comment: Seems impossible to both be objects when you have more than one. I assume you would want to force it to an array.... and I would not know since I have never used that library.

Comment: What are `response.data` or `xml`? Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: @jabaa Added the information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. XMLtoJSON library converts to object if there is 1 record. But if there is 2 or more record, it converts to array.

So in other to fix this, we should add `alwaysArray: true` attribute to options.

Answer (score 0):

You should have try some type definition in XML or it will happen when you convert xml to js. If XML node has only one child, parser will automatically convert it to an object.

Comment: I can't change the XML.

Comment: So you must handle it by yourself. You can check if it is array or not. like if( Array.isArray(result)) { rs = result; } else { rs = [result.child]}   in case of not null.